# 'find' template for handling any file

Tags: security, bash

After growing tired of all the ways in which a file loop can be broken (`find -print | while read`) or unreadable (`find -exec` with complex commands), I think I've managed to build a [`find` template](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) which can handle **any and all files** which could possibly exist on a Linux system (not so famous last words). Can you find a way to break it, by changing either the `test_` variables or the environment? For example, is it possible to mess with file descriptor 9 outside the script so that it won't work?

The only requirement is "sanity." In other words, `test_file_name` and `test_dir_path` cannot contain `\0` or `/`, `test_file_path` cannot contain `\0` (or be more than 1 level deep, since `mkdir` for the sake of the test is run without `-p`), and `/bin/bash` must be  a stable version of Bash 4.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Filenames can contain *any* character except only null (\0) and slash (/);
# here's some general rules to handle them:
#
# $'...' can be used to create human readable strings with escape sequences.
#
# ' -- ' in commands is necessary to separate arguments from filenames, since
# filenames can start with '--', and would therefore be handled as parameters.
# To handle parameters properly (like GNU tools) use `getopt`.
#
# `find` doesn't support this syntax, so we use `readlink` to get an absolute
# path which by definition starts with slash.
#
# The "$()" construct strips trailing newlines, so we have to add a different
# character and then strip it outside the "$()" construct.
#
# `IFS=` is necessary to avoid that any characters in IFS are stripped from
# the start and end of $path.
#
# '-r' avoids interpreting backslash in filenames specially.
#
# '-d '' splits filenames by the null character.
#
# '-print0' separates find output by null characters.
#
# Variables inside '$()' have to be quoted just like outside this construct.
#
# Use process substitution with "<(" instead of pipes to avoid broken pipes.
#
# Use file descriptor 9 for data storage instead of standard input to avoid
# greedy commands like `cat` eating all of it.

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o noclobber

test_file_name=$'--$`\! *@ \a\b\e\E\f\r\t\v\\\"\' \n'
test_dir_path="$test_file_name"
test_file_path="${test_dir_path}/${test_file_name}"

mkdir -- "$test_dir_path"
touch -- "$test_file_path"

absolute_dir_path_x="$(readlink -fn -- "$test_dir_path"; echo x)"
absolute_dir_path="${absolute_dir_path_x%x}"

exec 9< <( find "$absolute_dir_path" -type f -print0 )
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    file_path="$(readlink -fn -- "$REPLY"; echo x)"
    file_path="${file_path%x}"
    echo "START${file_path}END"
done

rm -- "$test_file_path"
rmdir -- "$test_dir_path"
```

Comment: Either nobody here knows bash, or nobody can break it. ;)

Comment: If you're talking about `gnu find`, you hardly ever need `find | while read`, or `for` or `xargs` and the like. Read the manpage for `find`, especially the part about -exec, -execdir, -ok and -okdir. Find already iterates over the the result, so you don't need an iterator to catch and rethrow the results to some other command or program.

Comment: I haven't found a bug, so have my sole nitpick so far: `printf "%q\n" "$file_path"` is nicer than `echo` (and there's an unbalanced quote in your comments).

Comment: @Tobu: I disagree with the `printf` statement (do you have a reference or more elaborate reasoning?), but thanks for the quote fix.

Comment: It's been 11 days, and a week of bounty, with no submissions showing functional errors in the code. As user unknown pointed out, there are more *elegant* solutions in case you only want to run a single command on each file within a separate subshell. But at this point I guess it's safe to say that this is a really safe way to loop over any and all files without tripping over names, executing arbitrary strings, prematurely terminating, or ending up with an undocumentable picket fence. Thanks to everyone who tried!

Comment: @sepp2k: IANAL, but it's *probably* not a good idea to copy code from someone's hyperlink and paste it to the site without explicit permission.  Content on StackExchange sites is CC BY-SA, so in theory, doing so could imply that the software has a license that the owner of the code never granted.

Comment: @l0b0: `echo` doesn't have a standard interface (beyond "none at all" anyway) whereas `printf` does. In general `printf` should be used in preference to `echo`. It also means that you can cleanly say things like `printf '%s costs $%d\n' "$string" "$dollars"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code is vulnerable to [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check-to-time-of-use). There is a tiny gap between the time that "plain files" are read from the process substitution (`find -type f ...`) and the time that `readlink(1)` is called on those filenames.

An attacker could create a program that waits for your program to run and then quickly deletes one of those files found by `find(1)` and replaces it with a symlink to somewhere else. `readlink(1)` will then dutifully return the target of that symlink and this is the path that will be output. The target could be outside `$absolute_dir_path` and a file of any type (directory, device node, ...).

Eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o nounset
set -o noclobber

# setup directory containing two plain files
# hardcode absolute_dir_path to /tmp/dir for simplicity
mkdir -p /tmp/dir
rm -f /tmp/dir/a /tmp/dir/b
touch /tmp/dir/a /tmp/dir/b

# emulate OP's find loop, but with inserted actions
# performed by an attacker (in real attack these would
# happen in an external program).
exec 9< <( find /tmp/dir -type f -print0 )
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
        file_path_x="$(readlink -fn -- "$REPLY"; echo x)"
        file_path="${file_path_x%x}"
        ls -l "${file_path}"
        # attacker jumps in here and does:
        rm /tmp/dir/b
        ln -s /etc/passwd /tmp/dir/b
done
```

Output:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 martin martin 0 2011-03-31 10:56 /tmp/dir/a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2119 2011-03-28 11:35 /etc/passwd
```

The risk can be mitigated by only seeking files in directories beneath which untrusted users do not have write access. Directories such as `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` are problematic though and this is hard to solve. See the source of (eg) [tmpreaper](http://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/tmpreaper) for some ideas.

Comment: Excellent observation. I guess one fix would be to avoid the `readlink` altogether (which would work since filenames would start with `/tmp/dir` in any case), and make sure that none of the commands within the loop traverse symbolic links.

Comment: Thanks! That's a definite improvement, but an attacker could substitute a directory or named pipe or... (or even just delete the file). That's less obviously exploitable but could still cause problems with whatever processes the supposed list of plan files (aim to "fail fast, fail hard", don't rely on pre-emptive tests).

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -execdir echo START{}END ";"
START./--$`\! *@

        \"' 
/--$`\! *@

        \"' 
END
```

In which cases to you fail with find?

```
find . -type f  -execdir md5sum {} ";"
\d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  ./--$`\\! *@

        \\"' \n/--$`\\! *@

        \\"' \n
```

(changed from -exec to -execdir after useful hint).

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean, your solution solves no problem.

Comment: How to loop over files is asked several times per day in different SO sites, and half-assed solutions are suggested every time. This was a solution which worked for heavily unit-tested code, so I thought it might be generally safe. `-exec` is nice if you want to run a single command, but my solution was also supposed to be readable if you have more complex commands to run for each file.

Comment: `find . -type f  -exec complexScript.sh {} ";"`

Comment: `complexScript.sh` is run in a separate subshell - You'd need to add parameter passing + parsing if you want any context from the source script. Also, for some reason nobody suggests using `-execdir` even though the man page says "There are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the -exec action; you should use the -execdir option instead."

Comment: You're right, I changed it to `execdir`. About parameter-passing and -parsing: Where's the problem? You need it as well.